# Lubuntu 22.04.2 intermittent wifi issues (Probook 4530s)

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, lubuntu

Im running Lubuntu 22.04 LTS on a probook 4530s with latest updates as of this post

The wifi is very bad, slow, and randomly times out while using the web. the PC does not report ever disconnecting from the WiFi itself.

While the Ethernet cord is plugged in it returns normal speed and pings from 8.8.8.8

When on WiFi, when running `ping 8.8.8.8` sometimes (not often) its completely normal.

Sometimes ping looks like this:

```
From 192.168.0.150 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.150 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.150 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
...
```

Other times it looks like this:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=110 time=242 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=110 time=89.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=110 time=309 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=110 time=985 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=110 time=215 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=11 ttl=110 time=289 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=13 ttl=110 time=216 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=110 time=161 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
31 packets transmitted, 8 received, 74.1936% packet loss, time 30443ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 89.001/313.372/985.017/262.048 ms
```

With huge amounts of packet loss

`lspci -nnk` output is:

```
25:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3592 Wireless 802.11abgn 2T/2R PCIe [1814:3592]
        DeviceName: WLAN
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RT3592 Wireless 802.11abgn 2T/2R PCIe [103c:1638]
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
        Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

Edit: `iwconfig` output:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp38s0   no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"FBI van"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 88:5A:85:F6:34:50   
          Bit Rate=86.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:996  Invalid misc:99   Missed beacon:0
```

Edit: Ran `sudo iwconfig wlo1 power off` and no improvement

I have set ipv6 to disabled as was suggested in a old thread, to no avail.

Is there any other info i should add?

Also how do i fix this?

I'm not super knowledgeable about Linux systems so please bear with me.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `iwconfig`

Comment: @Jeremy31 iwconfig output added

Comment: Does it improve after `sudo iwconfig wlo1 power off`

Comment: @Jeremy31 i turrned the power mode off via that command, no improvment.